# Adding cash register support to ASP application. Starting an exe from client side

Tags: javascript, asp.net, activex

What I want is to print from a cash register from an asp application, what this basically means is to call an exe file that operates directly with the cash reigister with the txt file to be printed. A more correct formulation of this problem can be found on [this link](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/software/aspnet/30041877/adding-cash-register-support-in-aspnet-application.aspx) .

The solution given there are the following three:

- Using a link pointing to exe file - an exe file is downloaded and it operates
   the driver.
- Using a resident program on the client computer listening on a port - the server
   connects to it and operates the driver.
- Using an ActiveX Object - the driver is operated by client script from the
   internet browser.

I want to do this not using any resident program, but directly from the browser. In that respect I found a solution in Java using Applets, which is fine, but I have to do it with ASP.NET, and the only way I can do that is by using an ActiveX Object, and the problem with the is that they only work on Internet Explorer, which is not an option.

After thoroughly searching the internet my problems ca be concentrated in the following question: How ca I run an exe from client side on any browser without using ActiveX Objects?

I know that this questions [was posed](http://www.codingforums.com/archive/index.php/t-43136.html) thousands of times, but is there any plug-in, loophole, some form of java applet from an asp page :), anything that can help me solve this problem?

**UPDATE:**

Thanks for the comment and answer. The solution we finally choose is than whenever a printing request is formed the main asp application updates the database with that request and a resident application scans the same database for changes and creates and prints the txt.

Comment: Using ASP.NET does not preclude you from using a Java applet, one is server-side the other client-side.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Luckily it is not possible (imagine the security issues if it was possible).

However, you still have some options:

- Offer the .exe to download. This is the most portable way
- Use a .NET ClickOnce setup. This will start an installer with a single click in IE and browsers which have the ClickOnce extension enabled. In other browsers it will provide you with a setup.exe download.